# Makefile: Compiling a llvm program as part of an g++ compiled bnfc project

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, llvm, clang++

I'm building a Compiler. I have already written a Grammar and a TypeChecker using [bnfc](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/). And now I want to use llvm to generate the llvm IR code using the Abstract syntax tree generated by bnfc. The llvm tutorial says to compile like this:

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```

What would be the g++ command that does same thing and generates a .o object file file instead of a program?

Alternativly to an answer to the above question I would also appreciate other approaches to make the makefile below work.

## the makefile

Here I have my current makefile, that doesn't work, because apparently clang and g++ don't work together :

(The problem lies in `CodeGenerator.o`)

```
CC = g++
CCFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -w

FLEX = flex
FLEX_OPTS = -PCPP

BISON = bison
BISON_OPTS = -t -pCPP

LLCLANG = clang++
LLCONFIG = -g `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core`

OBJS = Absyn.o Lexer.o Parser.o Printer.o TypeChecker.o CodeGenerator.o

.PHONY: clean distclean

all: TestCodeGenerator

TestCodeGenerator: ${OBJS} cgcpp.o
    @echo "Linking cgcpp..."
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${OBJS} cgcpp.o -o cgcpp

Absyn.o: Absyn.C Absyn.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Absyn.C

Lexer.C: CPP.l
    ${FLEX} -oLexer.C CPP.l

Parser.C: CPP.y
    ${BISON} CPP.y -o Parser.C

Lexer.o: Lexer.C Parser.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Lexer.C

Parser.o: Parser.C Absyn.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Parser.C

Printer.o: Printer.C Printer.H Absyn.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Printer.C


cgcpp.o: cgcpp.C Parser.H Printer.H Absyn.H TypeChecker.H CodeGenerator.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c cgcpp.C

CodeGenerator.o: 
    ${LLCLANG} ${LLCONFIG} -c  CodeGenerator.C
```

## the error message

And here's the error I get:

```
CodeGenerator.o: In Funktion `std::default_delete<llvm::Module>::operator()(llvm::Module*) const':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:76: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `llvm::Module::~Module()'
CodeGenerator.o: In Funktion `llvm::MetadataTracking::untrack(llvm::Metadata*&)':
/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.h:243: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `llvm::MetadataTracking::untrack(void*, llvm::Metadata&)'
CodeGenerator.o: In Funktion `_GLOBAL__sub_I_CodeGenerator.C':
/home/username/Schreibtisch/Compilerbau/3._Codegenerator/CodeGenerator.C:21: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext()'
/home/username/Schreibtisch/Compilerbau/3._Codegenerator/CodeGenerator.C:21: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:26: die Regel für Ziel „TestCodeGenerator“ scheiterte
make: *** [TestCodeGenerator] Fehler 1
```

Roughly translated from german:

```
CodeGenerator.o: In Function `std::default_delete<llvm::Module>::operator()(llvm::Module*) const':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:76: undefined reference to `llvm::Module::~Module()'
CodeGenerator.o: In function `llvm::MetadataTracking::untrack(llvm::Metadata*&)':
/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/include/llvm/IR/Metadata.h:243: undefined reference to `llvm::MetadataTracking::untrack(void*, llvm::Metadata&)'
CodeGenerator.o: In Function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_CodeGenerator.C':
/home/username/desktop/Compilerbau/3._Codegenerator/CodeGenerator.C:21: Undefined reference to `llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext()'
/home/username/desktio/Compilerbau/3._Codegenerator/CodeGenerator.C:21: Undefined reference to  `llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:26: the rule for „TestCodeGenerator“ failed
make: *** [TestCodeGenerator] Error 1
```

Comment: I think it's better if you only post your question when you are happy with it and it is complete, not some half question.

Comment: It's a bit time-sensitive. SHould I delete this and post a completed version?

Comment: I think it's fine now, but just a heads-up for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I now found the solution by myself and will leave the makefile that works for me here for posterity: (Mainly, I just replaced clang++ with g++ and used `LLCONFIG` with g++)

```
CC = g++
CCFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -w

FLEX = flex
FLEX_OPTS = -PCPP

BISON = bison
BISON_OPTS = -t -pCPP

LLCLANG = clang++ -stdlib=libc++
LLCONFIG = -g `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core`

OBJS = Absyn.o Lexer.o Parser.o Printer.o TypeChecker.o CodeGenerator.o

TestCodeGenerator: ${OBJS} cgcpp.o
    @echo "Linking cgcpp..."
    ${CC} ${OBJS} cgcpp.o ${LLCONFIG} -o cgcpp

Absyn.o: Absyn.C Absyn.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Absyn.C

Lexer.C: CPP.l
    ${FLEX} -oLexer.C CPP.l

Parser.C: CPP.y
    ${BISON} CPP.y -o Parser.C

Lexer.o: Lexer.C Parser.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Lexer.C

Parser.o: Parser.C Absyn.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Parser.C

Printer.o: Printer.C Printer.H Absyn.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Printer.C

cgcpp.o: cgcpp.C Parser.H Printer.H Absyn.H TypeChecker.H CodeGenerator.H
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${LLCONFIG} -c cgcpp.C

CodeGenerator.o: 
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${LLCONFIG} -c CodeGenerator.C
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect, `${LLCONFIG}` should come in final link command, that is in `TestCodeGenerator` rule. You'd also need to play with its position relative to other object files.

Comment: Thank you! I will check if I can get it to work that way later today when I'm done with another unrelated project.